# How can I concatenate two sibling nodes in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, string-concatenation

My xml is like this

```
<root>
<level1>
    <value1>A</value1>
    <value2>B</value2>
    <value3>C</value3>
</level1>
<level1>
    <value1>D</value1>
    <value2>E</value2>
    <value3>F</value3>           
</level1>
</root>
```

I need a desired input as "A+D". How can i achieve this using XSLT version 2.0?

Comment: I agree with @kjhughes - please clarify your question

Comment: typo.. desired output

Comment: I need new tags <value1>A,D</value1> <value2>B,E</value2> <value3>C,F</value3> as output from this xml. How can i do this with xslt 2.0

Comment: To better communicate what you want, why don't you edit your question and include the XML output that you seek?

Comment: My output XML should be like this.<root>
<level1>
    <value1>A,D</value1>
    <value2>B,E</value2>
    <value3>C,F</value3>
</level1></root>

Comment: @user80597, please see [**How does editing work**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work).

Comment: Thank you for your help but i am new to this forum and not familiar with the tools. Coming to my question, In the input XML, the value tags should be replaced by concatinated values(EX: A,D for value1 tag) same for all the three tags under level1 tag

Comment: How many `level1` groups can there be?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the "correct" answer  (i.e. one that does not hard-code the number of `level1` groups to 2 or the number of values in the group to 3, as given in the example) is:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="root/level1[1]/*">
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:value-of select="../../level1/*[$i]" separator=","/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following **test input**:

```
<root>
    <level1>
        <value1>A</value1>
        <value2>B</value2>
        <value3>C</value3>
        <value4>1</value4>
    </level1>
    <level1>
        <value1>D</value1>
        <value2>E</value2>
        <value3>F</value3>           
        <value4>2</value4>
    </level1>
    <level1>
        <value1>G</value1>
        <value2>H</value2>
        <value3>I</value3>           
        <value4>3</value4>
    </level1>
</root>
```

results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <value1>A,D,G</value1>
   <value2>B,E,H</value2>
   <value3>C,F,I</value3>
   <value4>1,2,3</value4>
</root>
```

Note that values are matched by position, not by name (which could be done, if necessary, by using a key matching on name()).

Comment: Haha, nice (+1)....  Ok, we can get more general, but I'm not sure it's what OP really wants.  BTW, you forgot the `level1` tag that was specifically requested in the output.

Comment: @kjhughes I don't see that the output as such was specified (other than in a comment, which I cheerfully ignored). Besides, it will be good for the OP to do at least *something*...

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <value1>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(/root/level1[1]/value1,
                              ',', /root/level1[2]/value1)"/>
      </value1>
      <value2>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(/root/level1[1]/value2,
                              ',', /root/level1[2]/value2)"/>
      </value2>
      <value3>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(/root/level1[1]/value3,
                              ',', /root/level1[2]/value3)"/>
      </value3>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Applied to this input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <level1>
    <value1>A</value1>
    <value2>B</value2>
    <value3>C</value3>
  </level1>
  <level1>
    <value1>D</value1>
    <value2>E</value2>
    <value3>F</value3>           
  </level1>
</root>
```

**Will produce the requested output XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <value1>A,D</value1>
   <value2>B,E</value2>
   <value3>C,F</value3>
</root>
```

### Update

**Or, if you'd prefer a more general solution:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
      <level1>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[1]/*">
          <xsl:variable name="valueNum" select="position()"/>
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="/root/*/*[$valueNum]" separator=","/>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </level1>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <root>
   <xsl:for-each select="//level1[1]/*">
     <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
     <xsl:variable name="field" select="concat('value', $position)"/>
     <xsl:element name="{$field}">
       <xsl:value-of 
        select="concat(//level1[1]/*[$position],',', //level1[2]/*[$position])"/>
     </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the output

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <root>
   <value1>A,D</value1>
   <value2>B,E</value2>
   <value3>C,F</value3>
 </root>
```

for all children of the first and the second level1 (in case there would be more than just the 3 in the example). Btw I would suggest to use a different name for the second level1, e.g. level2, but maybe that's just a copy-paste error in provided example.